# Clicking on a Link via Excel VBA - getElementsByTagName doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I've seen this manner of excel VBA before, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using Excel 2016, and I'm trying to navigate to an internal website and click on a link to start downloading a file and save it out to my desktop, but unfortunately, the code that I've seen that "clicks" the link doesn't seem to work.

Please see the code below:

```
Sub Downloader()
    Dim Browser As Object
    Dim Website As String
    Dim LinkList As Object
    Set Browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Website = "http://website.com/thingamajig.html"
    With Browser
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Website
        For Each X In .document.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If X.Title = "Link to Change Reports" Then
                X.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The code works up until the line that starts looking For Each X... After that, I get an error that states the following:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Automation error Unspecified
>   error*

Comment: You may want to include what error you are getting and on which line.

Comment: I just added it. I forgot to put it in initially.

Answer (score 0):

You must leave some time for the navigated document to completely download before you start to search it for the links.

Add the following marked lines to your code between the indicated lines:

```
    ....
    .navigate Website 'after this line

    Do While Browser.Busy = True Or Browser.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    For Each X In .document.getElementsByTagName("a") 'before this line
    ....
```